# MS-Access: SQL UPDATE syntax error, but why?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error in this SQL, and can't seem to figure out why?

The SQL UPDATE returns this on the error:

```
UPDATE Tankstationer 
SET Long='12.5308724', Lat='55.6788735' 
WHERE Id = 2;
```

Here's my code:

```
foreach (var row in reader)
{
   var id = reader.GetInt32(0);
   var adress = reader.GetString(1);
   var zip = reader.GetDouble(2);
   var city = reader.GetString(3);
   var adressToParse = adress + " " + zip + " " + city;

   GMapGeocoder.Containers.Results result = Util.Geocode(adressToParse, key);
   foreach (GMapGeocoder.Containers.USAddress USAdress in result.Addresses )
   {
      var google_long = convertNumberToDottedGoogleMapsValid(USAdress.Coordinates.Longitude);
      var google_lat = convertNumberToDottedGoogleMapsValid(USAdress.Coordinates.Latitude);
      Message.Text = "Lattitude: " + google_long + System.Environment.NewLine;
      Message.Text = "Longitude: " + google_lat + System.Environment.NewLine;
      string updatesql = "UPDATE Tankstationer SET Long='" +google_long+ "', Lat='" +google_lat+ "' WHERE Id = " +id+"";
      OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand();
      update.CommandText = updatesql;
      update.Connection = conn;
      reader = update.ExecuteReader();
      Message.Text = "Done";
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message it returns?

Comment: Why are you using OleDB with MSSQL Server?

Comment: "There is a syntax error in your UPDATE sentence"

Comment: Nope, it is a accdb im opening, but using SQL to update the db

Comment: string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
                                    "/Tankstationer.accdb;";

                conn.ConnectionString = connection;
                conn.Open();

Comment: @nickycdk - you should change the title of the question to not say MS SQL.

Comment: What are the values of google_long and google_lat e.g. do they contain single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Long" is a reserved word in Access. If you can't change the schema to call that column something else, put it in brackets:

```
UPDATE Tankstationer
  SET [Long]='12.5308724', Lat='55.6788735'
  WHERE Id = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is probably because you are executing a reader, but your query does not return anything.  Call `update.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try using update.ExecuteNonQuery() instead of reader.

Saw other comments too late.

I don't use access often, but mine it's using <"> for text delimiter, not <'>

Comment: Errr.. did you not see my answer?

Comment: Still getting the same error as before using update.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

"id" is being set to Int32 (var id = reader.GetInt32(0);) but you are concatenating it to a string (WHERE Id = " +id+"";).  Make sure that id is cast as a string value and not an int.

Comment: If I cast Id as a string I get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.